# Hibernate Error Update

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I'm learning Java and Hibernate, when I'm try to update the database, I get this error. Can someone help me?

```
abr 05, 2017 12:19:51 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.9.Final}
abr 05, 2017 12:19:51 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.h2.Driver, hibernate.service.allow_crawling=false, hibernate.max_fetch_depth=5, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect, hibernate.format_sql=true, hibernate.generate_statistics=true, hibernate.connection.username=sa, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.connection.password=****, hibernate.connection.pool_size=5}
abr 05, 2017 12:19:51 AM org.hibernate.spatial.integration.SpatialService <init>
INFO: HHH80000001: hibernate-spatial integration enabled : true
abr 05, 2017 12:19:51 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
abr 05, 2017 12:19:51 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
abr 05, 2017 12:19:51 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl makeLobCreatorBuilder
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
abr 05, 2017 12:19:51 AM org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry register
INFO: HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@7a4ccb53
abr 05, 2017 12:19:51 AM org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl configure
INFO: Envers integration enabled? : true
abr 05, 2017 12:19:52 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
abr 05, 2017 12:19:52 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb]
abr 05, 2017 12:19:52 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=postgres, password=****}
abr 05, 2017 12:19:52 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
abr 05, 2017 12:19:52 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
abr 05, 2017 12:19:52 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@45815ffc] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: 

    create table Usuario (
       userId int4 not null,
        userName varchar(255),
        primary key (userId)
    )
abr 05, 2017 12:19:53 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at br.org.thiagogomes.hibernate.HibernateTeste.main(HibernateTeste.java:17)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "usuario" already exists
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2270)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1998)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:570)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:406)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 13 more

Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        Usuario
        (userName, userId) 
    values
        (?, ?)
abr 05, 2017 12:19:53 AM org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener end
INFO: Session Metrics {
    20444 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    18666 nanoseconds spent releasing 1 JDBC connections;
    186222 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
    1747114 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    16843134 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 1 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
abr 05, 2017 12:19:53 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb]
```

I don't know what happening, because the values appears on the postgreSQL.

**My hibernate.cfg.xml is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">Thi181907</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping class="br.org.thiagogomes.dto.Usuario"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**My Entity is:**

```
package br.org.thiagogomes.dto;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Usuario {

    @Id
    @Column(name="userId")
    private int userId;
    private String userName;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

}
```

Comment: is there any relation of user with another entity?

Comment: can you share me the method you use to insert/update the postgreSQL database. it may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>`

will automatically updates the underlying database schema, when any change occurs in your entity model (triggered when sessionFactory creates a new session).

Remove this property to check if **hibernate.cfg.xml**  is the only place where this property is defined. If it works fine, then reason might be the difference in table schema which is manually created in database and your entity. In that case, drop the table in database and restore the changes in **hibernate.cfg.xml**. Update the property key to `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` as well.

`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"></property>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this setting:

```
<property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
```

it is used to speed up greatly the initialization of hibernate. The downside is, that hibernate does not know about already existing objects and tries to create them.